# iOS - Sharing viewModel between views

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have a view whose ViewModel configures the view. The user can update the ViewModel and this object is later passed onto another view which will reflect the state of the preview view. Here is an example.

```
struct ViewSettings {
   var btn1Selected: Bool
   var btn2Selected: Bool
   var btn3Selected: Bool

   init() {
    btn1Selected = true
    btn2Selected = true
    btn3Selected = true
   }
}


class ViewOne: UIView { 
   var settings: ViewSettings

   init(settings: ViewSettings) {
      self.settings = settings
   }

   func configureView() {
     btn1.isSelected = settings.btn1Selected
     btn2.isSelected = settings.btn2Selected
     btn3.isSelected = settings.btn3Selected
   }

   @objc func tapBtn1(_ sender: UIButton) {
       btn1.isSelected = btn1.isSelected.toggle()
       settings.btn1Selected.toggle()
   }

   @objc func tapBtn2(_ sender: UIButton) {
       btn2.isSelected = btn2.isSelected.toggle()
       settings.btn2Selected.toggle()
   }

  @objc func tapBtn3(_ sender: UIButton) {
       btn3.isSelected = btn3.isSelected.toggle()
       settings.btn3Selected.toggle()
   }
}
```

This setting is later used inside another view. If `btn1` is selected in `ViewOne` and when `ViewTwo` uses that setting, `btn1` in `ViewTwo` is selected too.

Question:
 I'm doing a direct mutation on the `settings` to achieve this. Is there a better design pattern that would let me arrive at the same solution?

Comment: You just need to be aware that your ViewSettings data structure is a value type. So if you make changes to ViewOne.settings those changes will not be reflected anywhere else but in ViewOne.

Comment: ViewOne won't exist in memory after ViewTwo takes over

Answer (score 1):

your viewModel is struct that means its a value type, even when you think you are passing the same viewModel to other views, in reality you send a different copy of viewModel not the same instance.

So when you mutate value in view1 and pass the copy of it to view2, if view2 changes the value again, your viewModel in view1 will not be updated, its not passed by reference its passed by value.

so If your question was that I am mutating value directly will it cause side effects no because they are different copies, but if you want the changes to be reflected in all the views that holds this viewModel then it won't.

**Finally answering your question**

> Question: I'm doing a direct mutation on the settings to achieve this.
>   Is there a better design pattern that would let me arrive at the same
>   solution?

At very first, sharing viewModel across view itself is arguable. Should this be done or not, as such the whole idea is opinion based. Some might say its fine some might say its not!

In general, I have seen people sharing viewModel across views but I personally refrain from doing so, but that doesn't mean that either of the approach is the only right way. Its best left to developers judgement.

**Few clarifications:**

```
struct ViewSettings {
   var btn1Selected: Bool
   var btn2Selected: Bool
   var btn3Selected: Bool

   init() {
    btn1Selected = true
    btn2Selected = true
    btn3Selected = true
   }
}
```

This looks more like `DataModel` and less of `ViewModel` isn't it? Its just a data container, no business logic, no data presentation/modification mechanisms nothing in it, its a plain data model. You are sharing `DataModel` across view and you wanna mutate and pass it on to next view I think its fine to go ahead with it.

Comment: I just need to copy the value of ViewOne's settings at the time ViewTwo is created and ViewOne is removed from the stack. I was looking for a better design pattern over straight mutation of an object. I saw examples of ViewModel Binding but I can't imagine how I could benefit for a simple use case.